# select an item for each itemsList in a List

Tags: c#, linq

I have an orders List like : <Id,Date,List>
Now I want to group the List By product Id from that list
But I didn't found a way to write

```cs
  from vente in OrdersList
                group products by OrdersList.Product.Id
```

Comment: If you're using EF Core, you can do something like this:

    `var products = _entityContext.Vente.GroupBy(x => x.Product.Id);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to group by the property of `vente` not by the list itself:

```
var query = from vente in OrdersList
            group vente by vente.Product.Id into productGroup
            select ...
```